# How to submit without closing the rich popup panel?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

```
<rich:popupPanel modal="true">
    <h:form
        id="myModal"
        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                alert('ok10');
                $( &quot;[name$='modalConfirmButton']&quot;).click();
                if (typeof evt.stopPropagation != 'undefined') {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                } else {
                    evt.cancelBubble = true;
                }
                return true;
            }"

                <a4j:commandButton
                    value="Cancel"
                    immediate="true"
                    onclick="#{rich:component(cc.attrs.idModal)}.hide(); return false;" />

                <a4j:commandButton
                    id="modalConfirmButton"
                    value="Confirm"
                    action="#{mb.confirm}" />
```

If I click the 'confirm' button using the mouse, it will validate the form, and will not close if there are errors.
But, if I press enter, it will not validate, and will close it.
If I put the 'cancel' button after the 'confirm' button, it will validade, show the errors, but still close.

Any idea how to make the 'enter' key to work just like the mouse click for 'confirm'?

Answer (score 0):

you should validate against `submit` form event, so it is not dependant on mouse-click or Enter key-press. Basically the behaviour you want, is associated with the button only. if you move that to `onsubmit` for your form, it should work.

Comment: same result here, unfortunately